# What DIY tools are very critical for plumbing works and repair?

Tags: plumbing

From my understanding, besides the pipes, I would need the following:

**Screwdrivers**

[image]

**Pipe Cutter**

[image]

**Pipe Wrench**

[image]

**Piler**

[image]

**Nut Driver**

[image]

So, are there other DIY Tools that are missing from my above list that is very critical for my plumbing works and repair?

Comment: You should describe what type of plumbing you have. Is it copper, PEX, CPVC, or something else?

Comment: @BMitch The plumbing would include CPVC and sometime metal such as copper.

Comment: Tubung cutter,water pump/slip joint pliers, basin wrench

Comment: That 'pipe cutter' is a PEX cutter. So more of a 'tube' cutter. It won't cut copper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Wrenches

### Pipe Wrench

[image: Pipe Wrench]

You'll want at least 2 of these, of different sizes.

### Tongue-and-groove pliers

[image: Tongue-and-groove pliers]

These come in handy all the time, have a few pair at the ready at all times.

### Strap/Chain Wrench

[image: Strap Wrench]
[image: Chain Wrench]
Sometimes you just need to get a good grip on a pipe, nothing beats a strap/chain wrench fo this.

### Basin Wrench

[image: Basin Wrench]

For those hard to reach places.

### Adjustable Spanner

[image: Adjustable Spanner]

A few adjustable wrenches of various sizes always come in handy.

---

## Tape Measure

[image: Tape Measure]

You're going to have to measure something, eventually.

---

## Pipe cutters

### Copper pipe cutter

[image: Pipe Cutter]

### Pex/Plastic tubing cutter

[image: Pipe Cutter]

### Hacksaw

[image: Hacksaw]

---

## Pipe reamer

[image]

You can get ones that do both inside and outside reaming in a single tool. You'l also want a bit of sandpaper.

---

## Pipe Cleaner

[image]

Used to clean up the ends of copper pipe before soldering.

---

## Taps and Dies

[image: Dies]

You might find yourself in a situation where you have to thread some pipe yourself. For this you'll need some Dies, and possiply taps.

---

## Torch

[image: Torch]

Working with copper is likely going to require some soldering, so you'll need a good torch.  DIYers usually grab propane, or butane torches. If you've got the extra cash and you'll be doing a bunch of soldering, MAPP torches are what the pros use.

---

## Hammer

[image: Hammer]

Do enough plumbing, and you're going to want to pound something into submission at some point.

---

## Putty knives

[image: Putty Knife]

You'll need this to scrape gunk off of stuff.

---

## Auger

[image: Auger]

A great tool for clearing gunked up drains.  Either manual or powered, the choice is yours.

---

## Glues, Puttys, and other gunk

### PVC primer and cement

[image: Primer and cement]

You'll need this if you're doing any work with PVC.

### Dope and PTFE tape

[image: Dope]
[image: PTFE Tape]

If you find yourself working with threaded connections, you'll want to have some pipe dope and PTFE tape.

### Solder and Flux

[image: Solder]
[image: Flux]

When working with copper, you'll probably have to sweat some joints.

### Penetrating oil

[image: Penetrating oil]

Great for those really stuck joints.

### Plumbers putty

[image: Plumbers putty]

You'll need this if you're installing sinks, and/or faucets.

---

## Buckets

[image: Bucket]

You'll always want to have a couple buckets of various sizes on hand.

---

## A Box

[image: Box]

The more jobs you do, the more left over fittings and other bits & bobs you'll have. The longer you do plumbing work, the larger the box will have to be.

---

## Gloves

### Leathers

[image: Leather Gloves]

You'll want a good pair of leather gloves, for when you're soldering and doing other knuckle busting types of work.

### Rubbers

[image: Rubber Gloves]

You'll also want some rubber gloves, for when you've got to touch stuff you'd rather not touch.

---

## Plumbers Crack

[image: Plumbers crack]

You can't call yourself a plumber, unless your crack is hanging out. It's also great for warding off people who have "just a quick question", or want to offer "advice".

Comment: MAPP is critical if you are going to solder brass fittings such as faucets.  Propane doesn't seem to get hot enough to make a good solder.  (Although it works great on pipe - pipe joins)

Comment: I've come to realize that trying to work with propane is a lost cause - even the slightest bit of water causes a problem with propane where MAPP just boils it away almost instantly. Save yourself the headaches and spend the extra few bucks to buy a MAPP torch

Comment: Outstanding answer with picture and descriptions. Clap Clap Clap.

Comment: Also crimping tools for pex crimp connectors.

Answer (score 3):

For the average homeowner I would also recommend:

- a basin wrench. Single-use tool, but when you need one, you really need one.
- A non-marking wrench (or a facecloth to wrap around the wrench jaws) is also very useful for tightening shiny fixtures.
- Oh, and you need TWO wrenches, a big one and a bigger one, to hold back when you apply torque.
- pipe dope
- teflon tape
- plumber's putty.

If you're doing soldering then you need a rotary cutter or two, a torch, solder, flux, etc. I hope you are not doing soldering as DIY as it's too easy to burn your house down and STILL get a bad join if you don't know what you're doing.

If you're doing PEX, you need PEX tools. PVC, you need a reamer and PVC cement and a felt tip pen.

A hole saw is also often required, and a Sawzall really helps if you have to pull out old plumbing.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the scale of the project, but I'm a huge fan of SharkBite plumbing connectors:

http://www.sharkbite.com/usa/?gclid=CL7bvK-T4LICFal7QgodzGEADA

They work with Copper and PEX (not sure about PVC, though) and basically turn plumbing into a game of Tinker Toys. Cut, debur, pop them together.

The time savings for most DIY projects make the expense of these connectors worth it to me.

Comment: I keep flipping my downvote to an upvote. These are a good product, but its like plumbing 201 not plumbing 101 which I think the OP is asking for.

Comment: Definitely an upvote if you have PEX in the house.

Comment: @Freiheit I kinda agree. I've never actually sweated joints. I had big ambitions to buy a torch and finally get around to learning it, but when I had to do some PEX retrofitting work, I became immediately sold on SharkBites. One of those rare new products that I truly get excited about. I had a plumber come in and spend 2 hours sweating copper on my furnace. And he forgot to add the shut off valve. Went to Home Depot, bought a sharkbite shut off, cut, cut, debur, *snap*--and I had it added in about 5 minutes.

Comment: I like the video @ sharkbite.com

Answer (score 1):

At least two buckets, plus a drip pan (like a kitty litter pan).

Theres some humour in my answer, but you're dealing with water! Something to catch drips, move water, and keep water contained while you work is important!